# Error while connecting with other database [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesSession.getDatabase(string, string) null

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am working on an Xpage application. I made the following connection

```
var configDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("172.18.15.130", "Transport" , false);
```

it gives me **error**  [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesSession.getDatabase(string, string) null

But following is the connection that is working fine.

```
var configDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("172.18.15.130", "RD\\AOS\\Configurations" , false);
```

This is the strange behavior and I am not getting it.
I have also used database.getServer() instead of this IP but it does not work. The weird thing is that the above code was working fine previously but now it is giving me error while connecting  with transport application

Comment: Check the actual error message in the XPages log file at <domino data>/IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT (or use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF for easier access to the log files). The error message in the log file is more detailed than "error [TypeError] Exception occurred"

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing my Xpage application with an anonymous user and this is why the Transport application (to which I was trying to connect) was not fetched as the ACL of transport declared anonymous user as No access. I change the ACL of my application and it worked.